# How to host multiple countries website on single domain?

Tags: seo, google, web-hosting, web-development, seo-audit

I would like to use single domain for multiple countries web site. So, instead of using second level domain for each country like:

```
us.mysite.com 
uk.mysite.com 
fr.mysite.com 
de.mysite.com
```

I would like to use same top level domain mysite.com but for each IP connected from US it will return US content, for IP connected from GB - GB content and so forth. Same for scan robots, google, bing etc.

What are advantages and disadvantages of using that way, especially for SEO?

Appreciate any response!
Thank you!